# Plotting nth root of x against nx on a graph.

Tags: exponentiation

I've spent the last two days trying to figure this out.

What I'm trying to do is rearrange this:

$$ x^n = \frac xn  $$

to make n the subject, to allow me to plot on a graph, with n being the y-value and x being itself.

Comment: Try to use Lambert W function. But I do not no how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $x,n$ are each positive.  Multiply both sides by $n$ and divide by $x$ to get $$nx^{n-1}=1$$
Now take logs to get $\log n + (n-1) \log x=0$, which rearranges to $$\log x=\frac{-1}{n-1}\log n$$
Now exponentiate both sides to get the answer $$x=n^{-1/(n-1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n-1]{n}}$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be straighter to start by rearranging to $x^{n-1}=n^{-1}$, and then directly take the $(n-1)$-th root?

Comment: Sure, why not...